# Access HTTP server running on the Onboard computer

Tags: dji-sdk

I was wondering if it is possible to access an HTTP server running on the onboard computer from a device (mobile or laptop) connected to the remote control on the ground. From the documentation, the uplink/downlink speeds of 24kbps / 16Mbps are satisfactory for our application.

Going over the available SDKs, the  "SDK Interconnection" or "MOP" caught my attention that offers send and receive functions for Onboard and Mobile SDK (Payload as well). However, this means that the send/receive from the ground are exposed on an android based SDK, i.e.

```
                      UART            Lightbridge        USB
 Onboard PC ---> OSDK ----> DJI drone ------------> R.C. ----> Android ---> MSDK
```

From this alone, it seems that we would need to develop network interfaces that are sending and receiving via the corresponding OSDK and MSDK methods. This might be easier said than done - especially for the android device.

My questions are:

- Is there a smarter way to do this?
- Is the implementation of Mobile SDK available? If so we can port the send/receive code to a Linux box to simplify the code

Answer (score 0):

The MSDK is heavily encrypted.
I've been doing some reverse engineering on it. It's not easy, recommend older versons since they not encrypted.

There's no opensource if that what you asked. Will never be.

Everything sent from the drone is dumldore messages. You can decode them without the MSDK, but it's not completly straightforward.

The messages are partly documented here:
https://github.com/o-gs/dji-firmware-tools/blob/master/comm_dissector/wireshark/dji-dumlv1-proto.lua

If I were you I would connect a 4g modem to the onboard computer. Saves you a lot of time.

Comment: I was hopping something could be done, since there is an OSDK equivalent of `accept`, `send`, and `recv`, across "pipelines" instead of "socketfd".

Thanks for the tip - having a modem draining some extra battery is worth the development time to do this.